# WebLogic Server 10.0/JPA 2.0 Compatibility

Tags: jpa, weblogic, jpa-2.0, weblogic-10.x

I am using WebLogic Server 10.0 and would like to use JPA 2.0. I have found that there are compatibility problems between the two. I have found plenty of tutorials about getting JPA 2.0 to work with Weblogic 10.3.x. Is it possible to do the same for 10.0, or would using JPA 2.0 require a newer WebLogic version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have JPA 2.0 support using WebLogic 10.0.

This is described in Oracle Document ID: 1091853.1

> Does WebLogic Server 10.3 provide full support for JPA 2.0?
>   
>    - WebLogic Server 10.3.4+ allows to enable full JPA 2.0 support.
>    
>    - WebLogic Server 10.3.0 - 10.3.3 partially support JPA 2.0

More details in this thread: [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1095616)

Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172421/using-jpa-2-0-with-a-weblogic-10-0

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasted way too much time looking for this! Answer accepted.